# Hello , i'm programming a android application when it builds the APK the compilation fails

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-support-design, android-appcompat

gradle of the app on android, the app runs perfectly in debug mode to my device Android 5.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cl.datacomputer.alejandrob.gogps"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['android-5.0.1_r1.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
 }
```

And this is error, i can't understand where is the error, sorry if my english is bad,but i try to understand, i need your help, if you need more details i put here, i read all questions about this and nothing worked for me.

```
   java.util.zip.zipexception: duplicate entry:android/support/annotation/colorres.class
```

Comment: I advise you to only use the specific modules you need from the play services, instead of the entire thing which is an incredibly huge library

Comment: Tim Castelijns how do i make this?, it's my first time on Android Studio and Gradle.

Comment: You have some documentation there : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup 
By using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` your app will includes all services. And probably you don't need most of them... If you need only Google+ for instance, you should use  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0`.  You have detail of each service on Table 1 on the link above.

Comment: I solved the issue with your recomendation, but a lib android.jar

compile fileTree(include: ['android-5.0.1_r1.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', dir: 'libs')

I Decompile and delete the .class of error directly and now make and APK and build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**First Compile the build with**

**Used the**

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

**Instead Of**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

And Also changed in Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 23.1.0 and 23.4.0 try this instead

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line -

```
{
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

or Try

```
 {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you run this command `./gradlew app:dependencies` and list the result?

Comment: This is the output of the command:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5v1cGSkTXBjTGF1NEVYelFYNEk